# Does D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP supports DirectX11?

Tags: directx, directx-11

I am wondering if D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP supported by DirectX 11 and above. I read a book which said it is only for DirectX10 and below, I would like to double confirm here.

Comment: The WARP software driver works with both the DirectX 10.x and 11.x APIs. Presumably you are actually asking what [Direct3D feature levels](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels.aspx) are supported by WARP, which is answered [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082.aspx#capabilities).

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 and later, WARP supports DirectX 11, including `FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0`.  On Windows 8 and later, it also supports `FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1`.  Details can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082(v=vs.85).aspx#capabilities).

Comment: WARP supports a maximum of ``FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1`` on Windows 7 RTM or Windows 7 SP1 without [KB2670838](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2670838/). Once you install it, WARP will support a maximum of ``FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0`` on Windows 7.